# Difference between "duly admitted" and "graduated"

Tags: grammar

I got my degree but it is stated that "duly admitted" but I am wondering if it is correct or not? Of course it is from university, so it might be correct, but I am just curious.

EDIT:

> This is to certify that
>
> Mr. Xyz
>
> After fulfilling the requirements has been duly admitted to the degree
>
> BS Mechatronics Engineering

Comment: When you say that _it is stated that "duly admitted"_, what is "it"? Where are you reading "duly admitted" when you're expecting "graduated"?

Comment: Its written on my bachelor engineering degree

Comment: "admitted" means you entered the program, "graduated" means you finished the program.

Comment: Can you post the entire text so we can see the context?

Comment: @Barmar i updated the post. That's what's written there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conforms most closely to this definition from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/admitted)

> to permit to exercise a certain function or privilege:
> *admitted to the bar*.

In this case, the graduate gets the privileges afforded to those who have attained the specified degree.

You can think of this as being admitted to a figurative "club" of people with that degree.

Comment: Thank you. I was just curious.